# Regular Expressions Python replacing couple names

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I would like to find and replace expressions like "John and Jane Doe" with "John Doe and Jane Doe"

for a sample expression

```
regextest = 'Heather Robinson, Jane and John Smith, Kiwan and Nichols Brady John, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, and Nancy Brown'
```

I can find the expression and replace it with a fixed string but I am not able to replace it with a modification of the original text.

```
re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s*and\s*[a-zA-Z]+.[^,]*',"kittens" ,regextest)

Output: 'Heather Robinson, kittens, kittens, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, and Nancy Brown'
```

I think instead of a string ("kittens"), we can pass a function that can make that change but I am unable to write that function. I am getting errors below.

```
def re_couple_name_and(m):
    return f'*{m.group(0).split()[0]+m.group(0).split()[-1:]+ m.group(0).split()[1:]}'
    
re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]+\s*and\s*[a-zA-Z]+.[^,]*',re_couple_name_and ,regextest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way using capture groups:

```
def re_couple_name_and(m):
    family_name = m.group(3).split(" ",1)[1]
    return "%s %s" % (m.group(1), family_name) + m.group(2) + m.group(3) 

re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(\s*and\s*)([a-zA-Z]+.[^,]*)',re_couple_name_and ,regextest)
```

Output:

```
'Heather Robinson, Jane Smith and John Smith, Kiwan Brady John and Nichols Brady John, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, and Nancy Brown'
```

Comment: Friendly heads-up that there is a mismatch between your function name and the reference to it in the `re.sub` call, which unfortunately is less than the required 6 characters for an edit.

Comment: @vulpxn Thank you for pointing out! I fixed it right away ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below regex to capture the items to be interchanged and use `re.sub()` to construct new string.

```regex
(\w+)( +and +)(\w+)( +[^,]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FoIijk/1)

**Example**

```py
import re
text="Heather Robinson, Jane and John Smith, Kiwan and Nichols Brady John, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, and Nancy Brown"
print(re.sub(r"(\w+)( +and +)(\w+)( +[^,]*)",r"\1\4\2\3\4",text))
```

**Output**

```
Heather Robinson, Jane Smith and John Smith, Kiwan Brady John and Nichols Brady John, Jimmy Nichols, Melanie Carbone, and Nancy Brown
```